# how to insert a CvPoint into a CvSeq with cvInsert?

Tags: opencv, casting

I'm using a CvSeq of Cvpoint and it is created by cvApproxPoly.
I need to delete some points and insert some new ones.
I can delete the points with any problem, but when I try to insert I get an error:
"cannot convert parameter 3 from "CvPoint" to "const void *"

the code I wrote is

```
Cvpoint p;
p.x=1;
p.y=1;
cvInsert (mySeq, i, p);
```

how do I typecast p?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try [cvSeqPush](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/dynamic_structures.html#seqpush)

call it as

```
Cvpoint p;
p.x=1;
p.y=1;
cvSeqPush(mySeq, &p);
```

Comment: thanks, btw it was just &p instead of p, so now it works with cvInsert too