# In OpenCV - How to Convert CvPoint to CvSeq?

Tags: opencv, convex-hull

In OpenCV - How to Convert CvPoint to CvSeq ?

i have CvPoints and i want to use to cvconvexhull2 Open Functions - but it accepets only CvSeq as input . Please help me out in this conversion ..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8312102/how-to-insert-a-cvpoint-into-a-cvseq-with-cvinsert

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to opencv [documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/dynamic_structures.html?highlight=cvseq#),

Here is how to create a storage for various OpenCV dynamic data structures and fill a dynamically growing sequence :

```
CvMemStorage* storage = cvCreateMemStorage(0);
CvSeq* seq = cvCreateSeq( CV_32SC2, sizeof(CvSeq), sizeof(CvPoint), storage );
int i;

for( i = 0; i < 10; i++ ){
  CvPoint pt;
  pt.x = rand();
  pt.y = rand();
  cvSeqPush( seq, &pt );
}
```